# How to Select a variable from a string of varying length in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to select a variable from a string in SQL of varying length, but have been struggling to do so.

For example, the string may comes in as:

```
Oracle Plug-in: Executing SQL statement: SELECT * FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() 
OVER ( ORDER BY "Example"."Example" 
DESC,"DETAILS"."DETAILS" DESC) AS 
Ranking,"Example"."FIRST_NAME" AS "FIRST_NAME", 
"DETAILS"."LAST_NAME" AS "LAST_NAME", 
"DETAILS"."CONTACT_ID" AS "RepID", 
"DETAILS"."DETAIL_NOTES_NUM" AS "DETAIL_NOTES_NUM", 
"DETAILS"."TYPE" AS "IMG", 
"DETAILS"."EMAIL" AS "img", 
"DETAILS"."EMAIL" AS "EMAIL", 
"DETAILS"."NEWS_DT" AS "NEWS_DT", 
"DETAILS"."FIRM_NAME" AS "FIRM_NAME", 
"DETAILS"."DETAIL_NOTES" AS "DETAIL_NOTES", 
"DETAILS"."CITY" AS "CITY", 
"DETAILS"."STATE" AS "STATE" FROM 
"DETAILS" "DETAILS" LEFT JOIN 
"DETAILS"."Example" "YXISMOBILE.MV_VMW_USERREPRELTN" ON  
"DETAILS"."CONTACT_ID" = 
"DETAILS_USERREPRELTN"."REPID"  WHERE ( 
"DETAILS_USERREPRELTN"."USERID" = 'clooby' ) AND ( 
"DETAILS"."TYPE" = 'LapsedPrdr' ) )  LimitingTable WHERE 
Ranking <= 200
```

I am trying to extract LapsedPrdr (which is a variable, but will always be in that spot AFAIK) from the second last line of the string.

I have been playing around with the Substring and CHARINDEX functions but have been unable to get it right.

In the code below (with LogMsg being the string) I was trying to retrieve LapsedPrdr to see if I could get it working even if it was static, but to no avail.

```
Select substring(LogMsg, CHARINDEX('LapsedPrdr', logmsg) , CHARINDEX('))' ,logmsg)) as TYPE
```

Sorry for lacking obvious knowledge or if this question has been asked before, and thank you in advance for any info regarding this!

EDIT: The string happens to hold an Oracle command, but the column is in SQL Server.

Thank you.

Comment: Could you clarify your question? What do you mean by "extract LapsedPrdr" ?  Maybe providing expected results will help to get across your message..

Comment: @Plirkee Apologies for my lack of clarity. By extract I mean to simply pull the text from that point in the string. So in my example above that would be to return LapsedPrdr from the bigger string. Though, LapsedPrdr is a variable, so I need to pull whatever populates that space. Hope this helps.

Comment: @marc_s I am using SQL Server, that specific column contains a SQL statement to be used on our Oracle DB. But the database this table is stored on is  MS SQL Server. So I will be using Microsoft SQL to extract the substring. Apologies for the confusion.

Comment: Please clarify.  You would like all text between ["DETAILS"."TYPE" = ] and  [) )  LimitingTable WHERE] returned as the value for TYPE given a string like the entire example Oracle plug-in query as the value logmsg?  You are writing your query in SQL Server, but logmsg is written by Oracle.

Comment: @Degan Yes, I would ideally pull the text from in between ["DETAILS"."TYPE" = '] and [' ) )  LimitingTable WHERE.] returned as the value for TYPE. The fact that the String (in the Logmsg column) is an Oracle command is causing confusion, which is my fault, I should clarify it in the question. And yes, I will be writing the query in SQL Server. Hope this helps, and thank you!

Comment: Can you explain more about the problem (where you get the data, what it;s used for, etc.?  It seems like you could change this to a parameterized query but without more context it's hard to know exactly what the best solution is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will likely need to add some +1's or -1's to the substring.

```
Select substring(LogMsg,
                 CHARINDEX('"DETAILS"."TYPE" = ', LogMsg),
                 CHARINDEX(' ) )  LimitingTable WHERE ', LogMsg) -
                 CHARINDEX('"DETAILS"."TYPE" = ', LogMsg)
          ) As TYPE
From Table
```

SUBSTRING ( string_expression, start, length )

CHARINDEX ( expressionToFind , expressionToSearch [ , start_location ] )

Comment: Thank you, this method worked perfectly (though I had to use the Charindex function instead of INSTR as I'm working off SQL Server). Thank you for the help!!